# D3 - best way to dynamically update a Pie chart?

Tags: dynamic, charts, d3.js, pie-chart

I am trying to dynamically update a Pie chart and I am not 100% sure if this is the best way to do it. What do you say?

```
            var arcsenter = arcs.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc");

            arcsenter.append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .attr("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.data);
            })
                .on("click", function (evt) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(evt));
            });
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hsfid/dr7X3/embedded/result/

Comment: Your jsfiddle seems to work just fine for me -- what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I have lot of code (similar) before and after enter() and for some reason it feels kludgy to me to write that much of code for basic data update.

Comment: This question has actually come up just yesterday again -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227397/d3-js-reusable-pie-chart-with-dynamic-updates Maybe that helps?